# Solving for all possible mappings

Tags: python, algorithm

I just came across an interesting question. The question is to solve for all possible mappings in order given an input. For an example, if I'm given '012' and have a dictionary like this:

```
mapping = {
    '0': ['p'],
    '1': ['p', 'q', 'r'],
    '2': ['m'],
}
```

I want to print:

```
ppm
pqr
prm
```

I was able to solve it recursively, as coded below in python:

```
def print_all_recursive(s, t = ''):
    if len(s) == 1:
        for value in mapping[s]:
            print(t + value)
            return
    for value in mapping[s[0]]:
        print_all_recursive(s[1:], t + value)
```

Now for fun, I tried to solve it iteratively but couldn't get it to work. Please give me some help!

Comment: I don't follow the relation between the input and output. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Vallentin I made a mistake in the output. Heiko Oberdiek fixed it for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `product` from module `itertools` helps:

```
import itertools

mapping = {
    '0': ['p'],
    '1': ['p', 'q', 'r'],
    '2': ['m'],
}

def print_all(s):
    for value in itertools.product(*[mapping[ch] for ch in s]):
        print(''.join(value))

print_all('012')
```

Result:

```
ppm
pqm
prm
```

And the result for `'1012'` is:

```
pppm
ppqm
pprm
qppm
qpqm
qprm
rppm
rpqm
rprm
```